# How to run jquery function when page refresh?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox. When it is checked, a paragraph appears. When it is unchecked, it hides. There is no problem about it. What the problem is: if I check the checkbox, when I press F5(refresh) button, checkbox is still checked but paragraph is hided. I want to make paragraph appear when I refresh page.

Here is HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something">
<p id="info" style="display:none">Yes ,checkbox is checked now...</p>
```

Here is Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#something").change( function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $("#info").show();
        } else {
            $("#info").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to trigger the event

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // this only runs upon the event
    $("#something").change( function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $("#info").show();
        } else {
            $("#info").hide();
        }
    });

    // trigger the event
    $("#something").trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check the state of the checkbox at loading :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function f() {
       if( $('#something').is(':checked') ) {
            $("#info").show();
        } else {
            $("#info").hide();
        }
    }
    $("#something").change(f);
    f();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current behavior is because you have the event handler for change. So when you do F5 and refresh, even though it is checked, there is no change.

You can just call this function explicitly in document.ready

```
function SetParagraphStatus() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#info").show();
    } else {
        $("#info").hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#something").change(SetParagraphStatus);
    // call it anyway for load.
    SetParagraphStatus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the change event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#something").change(function(){
        $("#info").toggle(this.checked);
    }).change()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){

    $("#something >#info").show();

});
```

Comment: You must add some summary of your answer apart from code to make your answer more clear.

Comment: Your solution would fire when the user is navigating away from the page - that means when the DOM is generated again, the `#info` element would still be hidden. Also, this question was asked nearly 2 years ago (11/2012), and actually balexandre's answer solves the case.